# Removing Pages from Power Pages Header

Tags: html, liquid, powerapps

With Power Pages being relatively new, I noticed there being very little information on managing the built-in features like headers and footers. I have spent a while now working with Power Pages and know how to edit the specific code that shows the links to your pages without removing the profile and logout hyperlinks.

The solution is very simple and only requires you to remove the code without having to add anything. This is very useful in cases where you are creating a PWA that you would like to package as an Android or iOS bundle. Since most applications don't utilize standard "Navigation" panes, this is impractical to have in your PWA or bundle. For me specifically, this serves the purpose of ensuring that NO USERS can access pages without passing certain JavaScript arguments that I put into each page.

The solution is posted below for anyone that would like to know what I did to achieve this, and I hope it helps with your future application development!

Answer (score 0):

The Solution:

Headers and Footers are automatically applied to every default page you create within power pages. The items contained within these headers and footers are elsewhere, however. This being said, you need to make sure you have done one of two things during the setup of your power pages site:

1. You need to use an actual web template, not a blank template when you first create your webpage. This will apply the Registration, Sign In, and Profile templates to your site without you having to manually apply those web templates.
2. You can apply the above listed web templates to your site. To do this, you will need to look into the Power Pages documents provided that explain how to do this.

However, I highly recommend you just start with a prebuilt template then just edit the data tables for this since it is much simpler than adding web templates to your site.

After you actually have those templates applied to your site, you can edit the code for them individually in the visual studio. Which you can get to by clicking on "Edit Code" inside the editor for your site.

After you open the visual studio, you need to look for the  html file located at the bottom of your resources, in the "web-templates" section, as shown here:

[image]

After you open the Header you are looking for a specific string. A lot of web developers don't recognize where it is because it is actually written in a markup called Liquid. Simply remove the following function from your code, and it will retain the header and all contents except for the hyperlinks shown for each of your webpages:

You will see this string:

" li class='weblink {% if sublinks.size > 0 %} dropdown{% endif %}' "

Then you see:

" {% if sublinks.size > 0 %} "

Below that function start are a bunch of "blocks" that follow. Each of these blocks represents one of your hyperlinks in the order they appear on your site header. Each one you remove will remove a hyperlink starting from bottom to top, as the function simply displays one link for each block, and that link that appears is controlled via a search/display argument. Starting with the " {% if sublinks.size > 0 %} " statement.

Final Steps:

- Ctrl + F and paste " {% if sublinks.size > 0 %} " to make finding the first instance easier.
- Remove all blocks that you do not want to have data, between the first instance of " {% if sublinks.size > 0 %} " and the second instance of " {% if sublinks.size > 0 %} ".
- There is more than one instance of this function however we want to mess with the first instance, not the second or third!!!!
- If you only want one page and then your Sign In, Sign Out, and Profile options, then delete all but one block from that first string and only your "Home" page will display in the header with the above options as well.
- Ctrl + S to save the file with the data you selected removed.
- Go back to your page editor in Power Pages.
- Click the Sync option to finalize the removal of the header options.
- Preview to make sure it worked.

Removing the Search Engine:

You can also use the same method listed as above for the "Search" option that appears by default. You just remove the block that shows the "Search" function and its corresponding styling code and then save it/sync it and it will no longer show in the header.